# ReSharper ContractAnnotation for Null Check + Out Variable giving counter-intuitive results

Tags: c#, resharper, jetbrains-ide, rider

I have a relatively simple extension method called TryGetFirst

```
public static bool TryGetFirst<T>(this IList<T> list, out T value)
{
    if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
    {
        value = default;
        return false;
    }

    value = list[0];
    return true;
}
```

It does a few things at once. It null checks the list, checks if the list is empty, and if not, returns the first element. Kind of like Linq's FirstOrDefault but with a built in null check. Nothing too fancy.

I'm looking for the correct ContractAnnotation syntax to communicate the following facts to ReSharper, but I can't seem to nail them all down.

1. If the list is null, always return false
2. If the return value is true, the list is not null
3. If the return value is false, the value is null

Given the following code I expect the following ReSharper hints, at least in Pessimistic Value Analysis Mode in Rider

```
if (StringExtensions.TryGetFirst<object>(null, out object value) { ... } // Expression is Always False

if (_possiblyNullList.TryGetFirst<object>(out object value)
{
    _possiblyNullList.DoSomething(); // No Warning
    value.DoSomething(); // Possible NullReferenceException
}
else
{
    _possiblyNullList.DoSomething(); //Possible NullReferenceException
    if (value == null) { ... } // Expression is Always True
}
```

At first I tried `[ContractAnnotation("list:null => false; => false, value:null")]` but for some reason ReSharper interpreted that as all code paths always return false and therefore the contents of the `if { ... }` were unreachable.

Next I tried `[ContractAnnotation("list:null => false; => false, value:null; => true")]` as I thought adding the true case on the end would inform ReSharper that a true result was possible. This is slightly better, but the `_possiblyNullList.DoSomething();` inside the if block was being marked as a possible NullReference and `StringExtensions.TryGetFirst<object>(null, ...` was no longer marked as Always False.

The closest I've been able to get to my target is `[ContractAnnotation("=> true, list:notnull, value:canbenull; => false, list:canbenull, value:null")]` which handles every case except for `StringExtensions.TryGetFirst<object>(null, ...` which doesn't get marked as Always False. I tried adding back the `list:null => false` line but it made no difference. I also feel like this syntax is a lot more verbose than seems necessary, but I'm willing to live with it if it's accurate.

I feel like I've run out of permutations to try. Is this just a case that isn't supported by the attribute or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It seems that `[ContractAnnotation("list:null => false, value:null")]` does the trick. At least with specified reqirements.

Comment: @GuruStron Another very close one, but at least as far as I can see it doesn't flag ```if (value == null) { ... }``` as always true in the else block. There are situations where list is not null but the return value is false and therefore the out value is null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`list:null => false,value:null;list:notnull=>false,value:null;list:notnull=>true,value:canbenull`